# PHP PDO MySQL Count Login Streaks By Date

Tags: php, mysql, date, pdo

What I'm trying to do is:
* If user is logged on within 1 day, do nothing.
* if user is logged on after 1 day, and is within 2 days, set count + 1
* if user is logged on after 2 days, set count 1

```
$conn = $db->PDO();
try {
   $stmt = $conn->pdo->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `user_logins` WHERE `user_id` = :uid LIMIT 1");
   $stmt->bindParam(':uid', $uid, $db->PARAM_INT);
   $stmt->execute();
   if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
      $stmt = $conn->pdo->prepare("SELECT `count`,`login_time` FROM `user_logins` WHERE `user_id` = :uid LIMIT 1");
      $stmt->bindParam(':uid', $uid, $db->PARAM_INT);
      $stmt->execute();
      $fetch = $stmt->fetch($db->FETCH_ASSOC);
      $loginStreak = $fetch['count'];
      $loginTime = $fetch['login_time'];
      $userPoints = $users->getUserInfo($uid, 'vip_points');
      if($loginTime < strtotime('+2 day')) {
          $stmt = $conn->pdo->prepare("UPDATE `user_logins` SET `count` = :c, `login_time` = :lt WHERE `user_id` = :uid LIMIT 1");
          $stmt->bindValue(':c', 1);
          $stmt->bindValue(':lt', NULL);
          $stmt->bindParam(':uid', $uid, $db->PARAM_INT);
          $stmt->execute();
       } elseif($loginTime < strtotime('+1 day')) {
          $stmt = $conn->pdo->prepare("UPDATE `user_logins` SET `count` = :c, `login_time` = :lt WHERE `user_id` = :uid LIMIT 1");
          if($loginStreak <= 7) {
            // login streak is lower or equal to 7 days, so give 1 point
            $users->updateUser($uid, 'vip_points', $userPoints + 1);
            $stmt->bindValue(':c', $loginStreak + 1);
          } elseif($loginStreak <= 14) {
            // login streak is lower or equal to 14 days, so give 2 points
            $users->updateUser($uid, 'vip_points', $userPoints + 2);
            $stmt->bindValue(':c', $loginStreak + 1);
          } elseif($loginStreak <= 21) {
            // login streak is lower or equal to 21 days, so give 3 points
            $users->updateUser($uid, 'vip_points', $userPoints + 3);
            $stmt->bindValue(':c', 21);
          }
          $stmt->bindValue(':lt', NULL);
          $stmt->bindParam(':uid', $uid, $db->PARAM_INT);
          $stmt->execute();
       }
     } else {
       $stmt = $conn->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `user_logins` (`user_id`,`login_time`,`count`) VALUES (:uid,:lt,:c)");
       $data = array(':uid' => $uid, ':lt' => NULL, ':c' => 1);
       $stmt->execute($data);
     } 
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
     die($e->getMessage());
  }
$conn = null;
```

So far I have come up with this, but it does not really work the way as written above. Any suggestions?

Comment: `strtotime('+2 day')` means 2 days in the future. Don't you want to check if it's after 2 days in the **past**?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "does not really work"? What _does_ it do?

Comment: @Barmar Ah.. Like this instead? `($loginTime > strtotime('-1 day')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it entirely in a single `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE user_logins
SET count = CASE 
        WHEN login_time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
            THEN count 
        WHEN login_time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
            THEN count + 1
        ELSE 1
    END,
    login_time = CASE 
        WHEN login_time <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
            THEN NULL
        ELSE login_time
    END
WHERE user_id = :uid
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out :)

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but didn't really quite work hehe.. `Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' login_time = CASE ' at line 7`, but I think I might have an idea about what to do :P

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `END` keywords

Comment: `$stmt = $conn->pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM user_logins WHERE user_id = :uid AND login_time<=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL _1/2_ DAY  LIMIT 1");`
I just did this instead, because, yours did work, but I was not able to update users "vip_points" in the same way, but thanks for that, now I know for a next time it can be done a lot easier!

Comment: I got another question for you. As mentioned above I got it fixed that way, but it's only every 24 hours, which mean their streak will be pushed several seconds or minutes every day. How do I code it like Pokemon GO's Claim Rewards where it's reset at 00.00 and not every 24 hours?

Comment: Instead of `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`, use `TODAY()`. That's just the date, and the time defaults to `00:00`. And you can use `DATE_SUB(TODAY(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)` to get the previous day.